# Incremental searching when typing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The backend RESTful API accepts a search text and returns a list of results.

```
List<M> Search(string search)
```

I'm using ng-resource to call the API.

How do you implement the incremental searching when the user is typing? Does it need a reactive framework? Or are there anything built-in sources to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the native `onChange` method?

Comment: Onchange will issue a request for everything typing. I want the the search be called only when the typing is slowed down.

Comment: Use ng-change plus debounce then: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions